# Wrapping logging within an exception object

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I currently have this class that another programmer in my team coded:

```
public static class SoapExecuter
{
    private static readonly ILog logger;

    public static Exception ExecuterException { get; private set; }

    public static bool IsSoapException
    {
        get 
        {
            if (ExecuterException == null)
                return false;

            return ExecuterException.GetType() == typeof(SoapException);
        }
    }

    public static bool Execute(Action action)
    {
        ExecuterException = null;
        bool passed = false;

        try
        {
            action();
            passed = true;
        }
        catch (SoapException se)
        {
            ExecuterException = se;
            logger.log(se);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExecuterException = ex;  
            logger.log(ex);
        }

        return passed;
    }
}
```

This is not very idiomatic and I would like to change it to something that happens within the try...catch clause.
Is there a way to not violate DRY and still stay within the idioms the language offers?
Of course I can inherit from the SoapException and log it but I'll have to catch a SoapException and create a new exception object that wraps it and then throw it only to be silenced one level above.
Any idea guys?

Comment: What do you mean by "change it to something that happens within the try...catch clause"? It's not really clear what you're asking. (As an aside, this is truly *horrible* code. It wouldn't be quite so awful if these were *instance* members, but I really hope you're never using this code in a multithreaded environment.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I know this is horrible code. And in some way it is multi-threaded, it's a Microsoft Dynamics CRM plugin. I would like to handle the logging within the exception object ctor and be silenced within the first level of the try..catch or some common function or some real language idiom that doesn't form horrible code like this. So that means: I do wanna catch an exception but I do not want to have to copy/paste the same try...catch block all over.

Comment: Short of using heavyweight stuff like profiler APIs or AOP solutions, we have to put up with this kind of code, or copy-paste.

Comment: @Anton: Should I create a function that contains the logic I need and call it within the exception?

Comment: @the_drow - re "it is multi-threaded" - just to make it explicit: you could *easily* have threads reporting the wrong exception with this code. The `static` members are very risky. Also, you don't synchronize access to the `ILog`, so the concrete implementation of this must *also* be thread-safe, otherwise even more chaos.

Comment: If you don't mind catching `Exception`, you might as well do that. Personally I would prefer a wrapper of the sort you pasted, sans global variable. It could return an operation result including suitably parsed exception data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you really want is not to handle that exception inside `Execute` at all. The responsibility for handling the exception seems to lie with the code that calls `Execute`.

Of course you can still catch it, store it in `ExecuterException`, log it, and then rethrow it using `throw;` — but the purpose of `ExecuterException` eludes me. It seems that you only need it for `IsSoapException`, which in turn is much better written as `ExecuterException is SoapException` anyway, which even takes care of nullness and subclasses.

I don’t think anyone can be of any further help than this without seeing the code that *uses* the code you posted. If *that* code queries `ExecuterException` only immediately after calling `Execute`, then you can (and should) probably just change it to a try/catch in that code. If it actually queries `ExecuterException` elsewhere, then you could consider having *that* code store the reference instead, but either way, it would mean that the code is pretty entangled spaghetti code and probably requires a major rewrite anyway.

(By the way, just to nitpick, the first of the two catch clauses in your code is completely redundant. If you remove it you get exactly the same behaviour — unless `logger.log` has a special overload for `SoapException`, but then you should probably restructure that too.)

Comment: logger.log treats SOAPException in a different way, yes.
And the ExecuterException is used only near the executer.execute()